# 422 Unproccesable entity / unexpected token al hacer POST con parámetros que son correctos

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, post

Ya he probado con jQuery y con el método `fetch()` de Javascript y el error es el mismo `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` aunque en el caso de fetch() se añade también el error: `{error: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"}`

Me pregunto por qué si cuando tiro los mismos parámetros en el programa *Insomnia* (parecido al *Postman*):

```
{
    "titulo":"Examen de conducir",
    "dificultad_info":"media"
}
```

Entonces si me da codigo 200 y me lo añade correctamente a la bbdd.

Me he asegurado de que solo el parametro `titulo` es el unico `required`. Aun asi he probado metiéndole todos los parámetros y nada.

El código de JS:

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:4000/api/examen'
    const Data = {
        titulo: "examen de conducir",
        dificultad_info: "media"
    }
    
    const Params = {
        headers: {
            "content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body:Data,
        method:"POST"
    }

    fetch(url,Params).then(data => {return data.json()})
                     .then(res => console.log(res))
                     .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Prueba retirando `charset=utf-8`. Puede que este sea tu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean

Comment: Hola amigo Lo probé pero no solucionó el error gracias de todas formas